# Can java thread object be invoked twice

Tags: java

```
public class GetCurrentPrice implements Runnable{
   public void run(){
      // some business logic
   }
}



public class Main{
   public static void main(){
       GetCurrentPrice gcp = new GetCurrentPrice();
       Thread t = new Thread(gcp);
       while(true){
           t.start();
           //once this thread execution is complete, restart this thread.
        }
   }
}
```

This throws java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException. What i am trying to achieve is, run this thread once, wait for it to complete, once it is complete, run this thread again.

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215548/is-it-legal-to-call-the-start-method-twice-on-the-same-thread

Comment: Haven't you found the API to check it? No problem, here it is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29. Btw 4 upvotes? I absolutely don't these users here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cant do that. From Thread.start() API: It is never legal to start a thread more than once.

Comment: You need to create a new thread the same way you created the initial thread.

Comment: Another alternative is to block the thread with wait instead of finishing his execution. Then if needed you can notify on the same lock from another Thread.

Comment: It's a lot better to just use an executor instead of trying to do the scheduling manually.

Answer (score 4):

From javadoc of class `java.lang.Thread`

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()

Answer (score 4):

While you can't re-run a `Thread` directly, you can use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to execute a `Thread` (or anything else that implements `Runnable`) periodically.

From the API:

> The schedule methods create tasks with various delays and return a task object that can be used to cancel or check execution. The scheduleAtFixedRate and scheduleWithFixedDelay methods create and execute tasks that run periodically until cancelled.

You can just create a pool with one thread, hand it your `Runnable` and ask it to re-run it each time it finishes, by doing something like this:

```
public class GetCurrentPrice implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // some business logic
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main() {
        GetCurrentPrice gcp = new GetCurrentPrice();
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        // each time thread execution completes, start a new one without delay
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(gcp, 0, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Threads in Java are not reusable.**

It is not legal to try to restart the thread in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the same Thread cannot be started more than once, but the same Runnable instance can be passed to different Thread objects.

More here -> [Initializing two threads with the same instance of a runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562505/initializing-two-threads-with-the-same-instance-of-a-runnable)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't start Thread more than once, You need to initialize new Runnable every time you want to start same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to repeat the business logic:

```
public class GetCurrentPrice implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        businessLogic();
        businessLogic();
    }

    public void businessLogic() {
        // some business logic
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main() {
        GetCurrentPrice gcp = new GetCurrentPrice();
        new Thread(gcp).start();
    }
}
```